# Allow computer on same network to get information from backend

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]

I am building a web app using React front end and C# backend. I want to allow users on the same network to access the app and make all necessary views and changes. I am making calls to my backend like so.

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5161/api/"; // Replace with your actual backend URL

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 1000 * 20,
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

And my backend C# project Startup.cs is like so

```
namespace Backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Register the web connector like this.
            // The steps are automatically registered as Scoped.
            // You can change the lifetime if required.
            services
                .AddWebConnector(options =>
                {
                    options
                        .AddAuthenticator<Authenticator>()
                        .WithWebConnectorHandler<WebConnectorHandler>()
                        .WithStep<CustomerGroupAddQuery.Request, CustomerGroupAddQuery.Response>()
                    .WithStep<CustomerQuery.Request, CustomerQuery.Response>()
                        .WithStep<InvoiceQuery.Request, InvoiceQuery.Response>()
                        .WithStep<CustomerAdd.Request, CustomerAdd.Response>()

                    // You need to do some work in this InvoiceAdd class before you can activate it.
                    ////.WithStep<InvoiceAdd.Request, InvoiceAdd.Response>()
                    ;
                });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services
                .AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();

            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // Indicates the path for your service to be reached.
            app
                .UseWebConnector(options =>
                {
                    options.SoapPath = "/QBConnectorAsync.asmx";
                });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but this is my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DoorpackConnectionString": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Temp;User Id=sa;Password=minedude12;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When users get to the login page it gives an Axios error that it cannot get from the server. Everything works fine from my host machine.

It's my first time building a larger scale project using a .net backend.

Comment: When deploying, did you change backend's IP address or hostname?

Comment: Make sure there are no firewall or network restrictions that block incoming connections to your C# backend from other devices on the network.

Comment: The backend IP and hostname have not changed I will try checking the firewall restrictions.

Comment: I think what Yasin is getting at is: did you change the `API_BASE_URL` variable to some address that isn't "localhost" when you deploy the frontend code?

Comment: No I did not change that variable. Should I have?

Comment: That variable is how you tell your browser clients where to call for API calls. You don't have the backend running on _every person's_ localhost. So yes, sort of important that you change that variable to the central server.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. Just to make sure then I should change localhost to the ip of the machine running the backend server?

Comment: Yes. IP address or if the computer has a DNS name you can use that. If any of your API endpoints allow a GET verb you can test is by using the full URL in your browser's address bar.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `sa` user - it's a security issue. Create a user that only has the necessary permissions. Also, it's probably not a good idea to post your password on SO.

Comment: Haha probably not but that's why this is a Temp database that I'm using so I don't screw things up. You're right should definitely not be using sa user though